# Passing comma separated parameters o a batch apex

Tags: batch

Currently I am passing one parameter into batch apex and querying the results. But, now i need to pass comma separated parameters and then i need to query records from all these passed parameters.

This is  how i am doing currently.

```
public class getCampaignRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    public String CampaignNumber;

    //Constructor
    public getCampaignRecords(String campNumber){
        CampaignNumber = campNumber;


    select Id, Name, LeadId, ContactID FROM CampaignMember WHERE Campaign.Campaign_Number__c=\''+CampaignNumber+'\'';
```

But how am i supposed to pass comma separated parameters and query the results

like this

```
public class getCampaignRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    public String CampaignNumber;
public String CampaignNumber1;
public String CampaignNumber2;
public String CampaignNumber3;

    //Constructor
    public getCampaignRecords (String campNumber,String campNumber1,String campNumber2,String campNumber3){
        CampaignNumber = campNumber;`
    CampaignNumber1=campNumber1;
    CampaignNumber2=campNumber2;
    CampaignNumber3=campNumber3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preferred Solution

You should supply a collection, such as a `Set<String>` or `List<String>` containing your desired Campaign Numbers and perform the query against that collection using an Apex bind expression:

```
private Set<String> campaignNumbers;
public getCampaignRecords(Set<String> campaignNumbers) {
    this.campaignNumbers = campaignNumbers;
}
```

and then query in your `start()` method:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id, Name, LeadId, ContactID FROM CampaignMember WHERE Campaign.Campaign_Number__c IN :campaignNumbers
]);
```

### Literal Solution

If you're being told that the constructor must accept multiple `String` parameters rather than a collection, just build the collection yourself and apply the same solution. (I would call this requirement a mistake, myself).

```
public getCampaignRecords(String first, String second, String third) {
    this.campaignNumbers = new Set<String>{first, second, third};
}
```

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for your quick reply. but requirement is to pass comma separated values. What could be the best approach if we want to do this using comma separated values

Comment: @AmitRajput That requirement doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "comma separated values"? A string like "A,B,C" or multiple String variables?

Comment: The requirement is to pass campaignnumber like this campaignnumber1,campaignnumber2,cmampaignnuber3

Comment: Just split the input string then trim the individual values as you add them to the Set<String> that David suggested. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm